# How should I handle secret tokens for open source android projects?

Tags: android, parse-platform, config

I am learning to build an Android app with Parse. As instructed, I need to initialize the Parse SDK with the following method in `Application.java`:

```
Parse.initialize(Context context, String applicationId, String clientKey)
```

And my question is how should I handle the `applicationId` and `clientKey` in an Android project so that I will not expose them on GitHub?

For web projects, usually there are something like `app.conf.example` for you to copy as `app.conf`, which is listed in `.gitignore`. When setting up local or production environments, you need to put correct secret tokens in `app.conf` manually.

I wanna know is there anything like this for Android app development?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Short solution :

I think you can just put it like that, e.g :

`Parse.initialize(Context context, String applicationId, String clientKey)`

on the Application.java.

Commit it as-is, and then use the correct `applicationId` and `clientKey` locally.

This is because usually there are no notable changes to the `Application.java` class, in any case that you need to change something, just remove the correct code, edit the class, push to github, and put the correct code back locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think it is not good enough to do all the things manually. I think ProGuard should be a better option. I will answer this question by myself when I have time to research on it.